# You have not defined a root partition / which is required for installation of Centos to continue

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, dell-poweredge

I am facing the following issue while doing an automated installation of Centos7 with kickstart.cfg

[image: Issue with Centos installation using kickstart.cfg]

I used the following options in the kickstart file

```
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
logvol / --vgname=cl --name=root --fstype=ext4 --percent=60 --grow
logvol /home --vgname=cl --name=home --fstype=ext4 --percent=10
```

I have an underlying disk of 1.5TB with RAID1

Any suggestions on this issue.

Comment: did you define `/boot` partition?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a full tutorial on how to do this [here](https://grantcurell.github.io/Create%20Kickstart%20Server%20on%20Fedora/). Here is how I set that up:

```
zerombr
clearpart --all

# Examples if you want to set up logical volumes (currently set to autopartition)
# part /boot/efi --fstype=efi --grow --maxsize=200 --size=20 --ondrive={{ boot_drive }}
# part /boot --fstype="xfs" --size=500 --ondrive={{ boot_drive }}
# part pv.01 --size=1 --grow --ondrive={{ boot_drive }}
# volgroup vg_root pv.01
# logvol / --fstype="xfs" --name=root --vgname=vg_root --grow --percent=20
# logvol /tmp --fstype="xfs" --name=tmp --vgname=vg_root --grow --percent=5
# logvol /home --fstype="xfs" --name=home --vgname=vg_root --grow --percent=10
# logvol /var --fstype="xfs" --name=var --vgname=vg_root --grow --percent=35
# logvol /var/log --fstype="xfs" --name=log --vgname=vg_root --grow --percent=20
# logvol /var/log/audit --fstype="xfs" --name=audit --vgname=vg_root --grow --percent=3
autopart --type=lvm
```

I suggest keeping `zerombr` and `clearpart` but then try it with `autopart --type=lvm`. If that works then it's a safe bet that for whatever reason it doesn't like the config you're providing. I don't see anything wrong with it, but kickstart can be touchy. Other things to try:

- Specify the drive in clearpart with `clearpart --drives=sda1,sdb1,etc --all`
- Try explicitly specifying the target boot drive with `part pv.01 --size=1 --grow --ondrive=boot_drive`
- Try ignoring disks you don't want to use with `ignoredisk --only-use=disk_you_want_ex_sda`
- Steal what I have above and see if that works for you and then modify it to your liking

### EDIT

**WARNING** On newer laptop and servers Intel (and soon AMD) have deprecated support for legacy boot. It doesn't look like your problem has anything to do with that but just a word of caution as legacy boot will soon cease to function.